# Spring statemachine JPA with multiple JVMs and a shared database

Tags: spring-statemachine

Are there any patterns for running Spring statemachine JPA with multiple VMs (Highly available apps) and a **shared database** or is distributed coordination such as Zookeeper always required for >1 VM

Thanks in advance

Si

Comment: Can you elaborate this question ? I think the fact that you are using spring StateMachine doesn't mean much. This question can be posted into generic Spring/JPA forum. I think you odds getting answer are better there. Good luck.

PS: I stopped using JPA with StateMachine as I was always running into same problem: when StateMachine desires to persist state it happens that referential integrity prevents it, imagine SM stores state field while you need bunch of other fields to be in place. But using SM without persistence I find very powerful and then using transition annotations to persist.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I am trying to understand is the meaning of [Distributed States] (https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-distributed) from an architectural perspective. Distributed architecture can refer to an architecture that is "Shared Nothing" - e.g where each VM running spring statemachine with JPA has a dedicated database. My question is whether one can avoid using Zookeeper in the case where the architecture involves a shared database (i.e not Shared Nothing)